# Use a while loop to display unlimited data in a 5 column Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: php, carousel

Is there a way to create a Bootstrap Carousel with 5 columns and use a while loop to output all the images? 
How would it work with rows and columns? 
This is my while loop:

```
  <?php if( have_rows('logos') ): ?>

<?php while( have_rows('logos') ): the_row(); 
        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('logo_image');
        $content = get_sub_field('name');
?>
<div class="item active">
  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: bootstrap grid have 12, so 12/5 = 2.5 , so you choose to use col-2 or col-3

Comment: but you can have another way to solve that , is to override the col-2 or col-3 width in your main style css

Comment: but how does it work with the while loop? Where do I put the col-2 or col-3? Can you show me an example?

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example :

```
 <?php if( have_rows('logos') ): ?>
<div class="row">
<?php while( have_rows('logos') ): the_row(); 
        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('logo_image');
        $content = get_sub_field('name');
?>
  <div class="item active col-2">
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"></a>
  </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[Bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):

> use **.col-**  for *Extra small* `<576px` ==> Example : *col-2 ,
>   col-6*
>
> use **.col-sm-**  for *Small* `≥576px`  ==> Example : *.col-sm-2
>   ,.col-sm-6*
>
> use **.col-md-**  for *Medium* `≥768px` ==> Example : *.col-md-2
>   ,.col-md-6*
>
> use **.col-lg-**  for *Large* `≥992px` ==> *Example : .col-lg-2
>   ,.col-lg-6*
>
> use **.col-xl-**  for *Extra large* `≥1200px` ==> *Example : .col-xl-2
>   , .col-xl-6*